# How do I remove these annoying error labels?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2022

VS 2022

[image]

How do I get rid of these annoying error popups while I'm typing? They even appear over the text I'm currently typing sometimes.

I'm not exactly sure when it started, I may have accidentally turned on an option by mistake, but I don't remember which option controls this.

Comment: Did you temporarily disable to confirm that it is comming from R# and not VS itself? If so, I'd expect it to be configurable somewhere here: _ReSharper | Options | Environment | Editor | Visual Studio Features_. I'm using Rider, so I cannot check, sry

Comment: I disabled R# and it still persists, I'll update the question to exclude R# now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tools > Options > Text Editor > C# (for example) > Advanced > Display diagnostics inline (uncheck)